# Rundeck Can we unite all .acl files that are created when we create a rundeck project

Tags: rundeck

We have an application for which we have a huge number of projects created in Rundeck.

Whenever any user creates a project, an `.acl` file is created for the project inside the `etc` folder with all the authentication details for that project.

So now the number of `.acl` files has become huge. This is impacting the login time performance as the application must read each of those `.acl` files on start. Is there a way to improve performance for user login, e.g. by unifying all of the `.acl` files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record answer: Sure, you can use a global ACL (Gear Icon > Acess Control ) and add each ACL separated by `---`, you can add system ACLs or project ACLs on that section. [Here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/document-format-reference/aclpolicy-v10.html#example-admin-policy) you can see an example.